# How to compare all defined names in two workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, named-ranges

I need to open two workbooks with same defined names, however different ranges, and highlight in one of the workbooks the differences of contents of every named range.

I compare hard coded ranges on one workbook with two sheets using the attached code.

```vb
Private Sub HighlightDifferences()
    Dim setOne As Range
    Dim setTwo As Range
    Set setOne = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Ongoing_Activities")
    Set setTwo = Sheets("Sheet1 (2)").Range("Ongoing_Activities")

    'REMOVE THE COLOR FILL
    setOne.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

    For Each cellitem In setOne
        If Not StrComp(cellitem, cellitem2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
            cellitem.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End If

        For Each cellitem2 In setTwo
            If StrComp(cellitem, cellitem2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                cellitem.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
            End If
        Next cellitem2
    Next cellitem

End Sub
```

Comment: The code as it is cannot work without an error on the line `If Not StrComp(cellitem, cellitem2, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then`, since `cellitem2` has not been set.

Comment: Anyhow, the logic behind the code looks wrong. It will make yellow all cells, if there are not identic values in different positions, because it tries compare on cell with all the other. Do the workbook in discussion have identic names with different sheets scope?

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub compareNamesTwoWorkbooks()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, N1 As Name, N2 As Name, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rngN1 As Range, rngN2 As Range, boolFound As Boolean
    
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("first workbook.xlsx")
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("second workbook.xlsx")
    
    For Each N1 In wb1.Names
        For Each N2 In wb2.Names
            If N1.RefersTo = N2.RefersTo Then
                Set rngN1 = Application.Evaluate("'[" & wb1.Name & "]" & _
                                Replace(Replace(N1.RefersTo, "=", ""), "!", "'!"))
                Set rngN2 = Application.Evaluate("'[" & wb2.Name & "]" & _
                                Replace(Replace(N2.RefersTo, "=", ""), "!", "'!"))
                rngN1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone: 'rngN1.Parent.Activate: Stop

                For i = 1 To rngN1.rows.count
                    For j = 1 To rngN1.Columns.count
                        If Not StrComp(rngN1.cells(i, j).Value, _
                             rngN2.cells(i, j).Value, vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                             rngN1.cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                        End If
                    Next j
                Next i
                boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next N2
        If Not boolFound Then Debug.Print "Names """ & N1.Name & _
                    """ could not be found in workbook """ & wb2.Name
        boolFound = False
    Next N1
End Sub
```

Please, **take care of using your real names to define `wb1` and wb2` workbooks**. Of course, they must be open. They can also be open by the program if needed.
After testing, some feedback would be appreciated...

Comment: Many thanks for your efforts.
The macro runs with messages in the "Immediate" window of several names that could not be found in the second workbook, which is not the case, as same names exist in both workbooks. It is worth to mention that the ranges might not be the same, so is the data in each cell within the range and this is what I need to highlight.

Comment: @Zak Nazif: You firstly must learn how to ask a question. Secondly, you must answer clarification questions. Then, "same names" is a relative concept. I asked you if "the workbook in discussion have identic names with different sheets scope", but you did not answer, even now... Since you were speaking about comparing of two sheets with the same Name, I could only assumed that the names to be compared have the sheet scope, if you know what this means...

Comment: @Zak Nazif: Coming with a piece of code which could not work in any circumstances and say "I am able to compare", which is obviously not true, I feel I wasted my time. The results in Immediate Window are the result of Named ranges which does not match in terms of scope and range address. If this is the case, please try explaining which is your real situation and what do you really want accomplishing. How to compare each cell of two ranges not having the same address?

Comment: Need to perform the following:

1- Select and open two or more workbooks. 2- Compare each sheet with identical name in all open workbooks. 3- Highlight all non-existing values in cells within each dynamic Named Range with identical name within each identical sheet.

Notes:
1- Need to set Named Ranges to be dynamic.
2- Named Ranges are not contiguous. 3- Named Ranges already have merged cells.

Thanks for all assistance.